# Can I update the a Stripe Coupon from the Dashboard?

Tags: stripe-payments

I've created a stripe coupon, but accidentally made the "maximum redemptions" field too low of a number.  I'd like to increase it.

Selecting edit in the dashboard only allows me to edit the name, and if I try to create a new coupon of the same name, I get an ID conflict error.

I'd like to not delete the previous coupon because it has valuable information (when it was used, etc.).

How can I update the current coupon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you delete the coupon then recreate a coupon of the same id (with different data), the event log appears to remain intact, although the redemption count does drop back to zero.

Comment: You're correct that you need to create a different coupon to change anything. You don't have to delete the original coupon, although that is of course an option. Either way, the new coupon won't share anything with the original one.